# How to check Whether the Current User has Already Like or Dislike the comment

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, t-sql

I have two tables in mysql database

1. tbl_comments
2. tbl_user_votes

There are three fields in tbl_user_votes

```
1. comment_id, 2. user_id, 3.vote_type ('L' OR 'D') (L for Like, D For Dislike)
```

I have a pagination scheme and according to that each of my webpage has 20 comments. Each comment has a Like and Dislike button. When A logged in user clicks on Like or Dislike, Three values are inserted in `tbl_users_votes, 1. comment_id, 2. user_id, 3. vote_type (L OR D).`

I want that When page Reloads, all the Comments Where he has clicked "Like" or "Dislike", must show, "You Like" or "You Dislike" under the comment.

My Problem is, I am not going to make an efficient algorithm for this problem.
I have thought such like solution.

I have to run an SQL Query for each comment like this `"SELECT * From tbl_user_votes where comment_id = xyz and user_id = xyz"` and then Check whether there Some value exists against that user_id and comment_id or not. If exists then I check the value and Put and If else condition on each comment like this

```
If(vote_found)
  If(vote_type=='L')
   echo "You Like"
  else if(vote_type=='D')
   echo "You Dislike'
```

But I think this is not an efficient way to do this. It looks very memory and time consuming process as if there are 20 comments on the page and on each comment a sql query to database is very expensive.

Can any one has some better and more efficient way to deal with this problem.

Comment: 1. Fetch all the posts. 2. Loop through the posts, get their ids. 3. Fetch all the votes `WHERE comment_id IN (...)`. 4. Correlate the data. -- Alternatively you can probably do it with *one* `LEFT JOIN` query.

Comment: I have faced this problem a lot of time and I could not find an efficient solution to this. It is easy to find a solution but not an easy one. I suppose that we can use a nosql DB for something like this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a query that will give you also votes in one record set.

```
SELECT
  tbl_comments.*,
  tbl_users.*
FROM
  tbl_comments LEFT JOIN tbl_users
  ON tbl_comments.user_id = tbl_users.user_id2
WHERE
  (tbl_users.user_id="xxx")
  OR (tbl_users.user_id IS NULL);
```

I don't know what is your index in `tbl_users` so I assumed `user_id2`, change it if needed.

Using `LEFT JOIN` will give you all comments of that user and if there exists one, a user vote. If `tbl_comments.user_id` is `NULL`, then there is no comment.